# Is there a shorthand for the unsigned long long type?

Tags: c, types, syntax, unsigned, unsigned-long-long-int

The type:

```
unsigned long long my_num;
```

seems cumbersome. I seem to recall seeing a shorthand for it, something like:

```
ull my_num;
```

Am I going mad, or is there a simpler way of writing `unsigned long long`?

Comment: I use `xxx` and then search/replace `xxx` with `unsigned long long` at the coding session end.  Code for clarity, not shorthand.

Comment: yes, you can use 'ull' instead of 'unsigned long long'

Comment: You could use `typedef unsigned long long ull;`. However, choosing a name more suitable for your application would be better, such as `typedef unsigned long long FooType;`.

Comment: C doesn't give you shorthands. C gives you a way to create shorthands if you need them.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Would you use the `typedef unsigned long long ull` method? Or is there a reason not to do that?

Comment: @Connor You can certainly do that. The reason not to is that whoever reads your code (including you, a week from now) will have to then go figure out what `ull` is. If you're using that type very frequently, `ull` might be preferable for its brevity. If you're using it in three places, `unsigned long long` might save the reader the trouble of needing to find the definition of something unfamiliar. It's a judgement call.

Comment: @Connor "Or is there a reason not to do that?:" --> Answer [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75961247/2410359).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no type named `ull`. `ull` can be used as a suffix when specifying an integer constant such as:

```c
unsigned long long my_num = 1ull;
```

You can read more about integer constants in the C standard [section 6.4.4.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1).

If you insist on using `ull` as a type name, although I would advise against this*, you can use `typedef`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
 
typedef unsigned long long ull;
int main() {
    ull a = 20ull;
    printf("%llu\n", a);
}
```

*As others have pointed out there is no clear advantage to using such a shorthand and at the very least it makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a simpler way of writing `unsigned long long` (?)

Yes, depending on goal.

First ask why is code using `unsigned long long`?

**Use `uintmax_t` from `<inttypes.h>`**
If the goal is to use the widest available integer type, then use `uintmax_t`.  `uintmax_t` and `unsigned long long` types are at *least* 64-bit.  `uintmax_t` is the widest available specified integer type and may be wider than `unsigned long long`.

**Use `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>`**
If the goal is to use a 64-bit integer type, then use `uint64_t`.  It is exactly 64-bits.  `unsigned long long` may be 64-bits or wider.

**Use `unsigned long long`**
If the goal really is to `unsigned long long`, then use `unsigned long long` and not a *shorthand* or some `typedef` such as `typedef unsigned long long ull;`.  In forming this answer, I did not type `unsigned long long`, but used copy & paste.  `unsigned long long` is clear.  `ull` is not a universal nor standard substitute for `unsigned long long` and such shorthands lead to less clear and non-portable code due to name collisions and the need to find the `ull` typedef to discern if it is as hoped.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what your looking for.

stdint.h

int8_t
int16_t
int32_t
int64_t
uint8_t
uint16_t
uint32_t
uint64_t

Comment: None of those are universally equivalent to `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm a novice so please expound on this, my understanding is on most platforms uint64_t and unsigned long long will be equal. uint64_t will guarantee 64 bits where as unsigned long long won't always depending on the platform or compilor.

Comment: Re “on most platforms uint64_t and unsigned long long will be equal”: And on some platforms, they are not, therefore they are not universally equivalent. If you write a program that depends on `X` to be `unsigned long long` but uses `uint64_t` to define it, then that program will not work on some platforms. `uint64_t` is not a universal equivalent for `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Is `unsigned long long` larger or smaller in those cases where they're not equal?

Comment: I believe uint64_t will be guaranteed to be exactly 64 bits unsigned while unsigned long long will usually be equal but may be larger, but never smaller.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ULL, but only on the right side of the assignement as long as I remember

Example: unsigned long long myValue = 123456789ULL;

but ULL myValue = 123456789ULL; shouldn't work